# Excel outline subtotal

Tags: excel, format, subtotal

I have an excel sheet where I have applied the subtotal outline command. Everything works fine, but I need the subtotal in the date column to return the elapsed time ("[h]: mm: ss").
I have succeeded by replacing each subtotal command in the column manually.
example:

```
"= SUBTOTAL (4, A54027: A55895)" and replace it with 
"= SUBTOTAL (4, A54027: A55895) -SUBTOTAL (5, A54027: A55895)" and then apply the format "[h]: mm: ss".
```

when there are many commands to replace is very tedious and cumbersome.
Could you help me automate this process?

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

this is the code I have developed.
it is possible to improve it!!!
I am interested in checking if the range where the subtotal function is applied is of type DATE; some suggestion!!!!.

```
Sub updateSubtotal()
Dim myRange As Range
    Dim fit As String, newformula As String, c As Variant

    ' insert a range
    Set myRange = Application.InputBox("Range:", Type:=8)
    ' IsDate(c):
    For Each c In myRange

       If Mid(c.Formula, 1, 4) = "=SUB" Then

        fit = c.Formula
        newformula = fit
        Mid(newformula, 11, 1) = "4"
        Mid(fit, 1, 1) = "-"
        Mid(fit, 11, 1) = "5"
        newformula = newformula & fit
        c.Offset(rowOffset:=3, columnOffset:=0) = newformula
        c.Offset(rowOffset:=3, columnOffset:=0).NumberFormat = "[h]:mm:ss"
       Else
        GoTo nextcell
       End If

nextcell:   Next


End Sub
```